# Choosing the right format/codec for export

Tags: premiere, file-formats, codec, cs5

I have a few recordings from my [Canon IXUS 90 IS](http://www.trustedreviews.com/Canon-IXUS-90-IS_Digital-Camera_review) that I have combined into one sequence. I am using this small project as a way to get to know **Adobe Premiere Pro CS5**.

The pieces of video from the camera are obviously already compressed, and I would like to export the finished product in an equally compressed format to reduce the file size. Which format/codec is best suited for this task? Am I fine with the ones that are already available to me in Premiere, or should I download another somewhere?

I've already tried the **Windows Media** codec, but I get the error "**The source and output audio channels are not compatible or a conversion does not exist**" and I have no idea what to do about this.

Video details:

- File type: AVI
- Video: 640x480, 30 fps
- Audio: 44100 Hz, 16-bit, Mono

I am fine with having to fiddle with the parameters in order to get the quality just right. I just need a pointer in the right direction.

Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: I use these guidelines when uploading to the internet: http://vimeo.com/help/compression. I know that's not what you're trying to do but it's a starting point. I find there is very little loss of quality and massively reduced file size.

Comment: That was actually just what I was trying to do, so thanks, it helped a lot. Could you post this as an answer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [these](http://vimeo.com/help/compression) guidelines when uploading to the internet. I know that's not what you're trying to do but it's a starting point. I find there is very little loss of quality and massively reduced file size.